# code to get add widgets to homescreen on Long click-custom launcher

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I am trying to create a custom launcher.I need to add widgets to homescreen on long press from homescreen, just like normal launchers.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

For you activity to become a launcher you need to add an intent-filter to the activity in the manifest, like this:

```
<activity android:name="AppLauncher"
android:label="AppLauncher" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

This is a complete tutorial on creating your won WidgetHost so you can add widget etc
http://leonardofischer.com/hosting-android-widgets-my-appwidgethost-tutorial/

Here you have a complete tutorial on making your first launcher app with app grid and all
http://www.taywils.me/2011/07/05/buildanapplicationlauncherwithandroid.html

Hope it helped!

Comment: If this helped you in any way please mark it as answered, thanks